# "while" command in c++

Tags: c++

In c++, I have to write a code to get the user's desired numbers in each line with "while" command and when the user enter number -1 at the end, I have to display the largest number, the largest number other than the previous number, and the number of row with the largest number entered. For example user's numbers is:

```
4
7
11
5
-1
```

and result is:

```
11(the biggest number)
7(the biggest number after 11)
3(the row that the user has entered the largest number)
```

This is my own code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()

{
int price;
int max=0;
cin>>price;
while(price!=-1)
{
    while(price>max)
    {   
    
    max=price;
    }

cin>>price;
}
cout<<max;
    return 0;   
}
```

I can find the largest number, but not the other two variables. Please reply ASAP.

Comment: You didn't show your code how you got your largest number, and what you did for the other two.  [mcve] will be very helpful.  Help us help you.

Comment: Where is your own attempt for this homework?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to spoon feed you the code. I will help you with the logic instead.

1. Take input and store it in an array.
2. Then use a sorting algorithm (there are tons of them, another opportunity for you to learn) to sort the array (or the vector)
3. Print the array

---

View the code only when you learn how to do it on your own:

---

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec;
int input = 0;
while (input != -1) {
    std::cin >> input;
    vec.push_back(input);
}
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
for (auto& element : vec) {
    std::cout << element << " ";
}
```